# Nginx 302 redirect - resolve internally

Tags: nginx, redirect

Currently, we have a server that implements a 302 redirect to server some content. For example, the user request:

```
http://origin1.example.com/m3ugen/segsrc/jet480.mp4
```

And this server responds with 302 and serves:

```
http://origin1.example.com/Segments/HLS_TS/segsrc/jet480.mp4-20140831-142558.m3u8`
```

This is problematic for us and we would like to let Nginx handle this to be more user friendly and to work with some players that does not handle 302 redirection.

What we want is:

1. User request `http://frontend.example.com/hls/jet480.mp4.m3u8` and received by nginx.
2. Nginx make request to `http://origin1.example.com/m3ugen/segsrc/jet480.mp4`
3. Nginx receive redirect code 302 `http://origin1.example.com/Segments/HLS_TS/segsrc/jet480.mp4-20140831-142558.m3u8`
4. Nginx make request to `http://origin1.example.com/Segments/HLS_TS/segsrc/jet480.mp4-20140831-142558.m3u8` and serve the response directly to the user without any 302 redirection.

I think that this could be done with Nginx but we have no much experience about it. Any help will be very appreciated.

P.D. We can't configure the origin server. It uses Helix Server and when serves the m3u8 playlist it adds a timestamp that changes for every file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not ideal and it would be far better to have a clean workflow instead of doing this.
But for curiosity, this could be informative to people that would wonder if it's possible.

**Yes it is**, using a combination of `error_page`, `rewrite`, `map`, `proxy_intercept_errors` and `proxy_redirect` directives and `$upstream_http` var pattern.

Keep in mind that it's going far off the path nginx is designed to be driven on.

```
map $upstream_http_location $redirect_uri {
    "~http://[^/]+/(?<location_uri>.*)$" "$location_uri";
}

upstream origin {
    server origin1.com;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name nginx-front.com;

    proxy_set_header Host "origin1.com";
    proxy_redirect http://origin1.com/ /;

    location ~ ^/hls/(\w+)\.mp4\.m3u8$ {
        proxy_pass http://origin/m3ugen/segsrc/$1.mp4;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 = @handler;    
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite ^ /$redirect_uri break;
        proxy_pass http://origin;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help! I have tried to implement this but i get an error, "unknown directive "error_code"  . I have made a clean Nginx install but it didn't help. I have tried with nginx 1.0.15 and 1.6.2 . It could be great to know what could be causing this.

Thanks in advance Xavier.

Comment: @Dakser Typo, replace error_code with error_page.

Comment: as in original example this scenario is useful for huge blobs on like S3. Server might do some stuff like authentication then redirect to the actual blob storage, this way blob wouldn't be transferred through BE (full path nginx-BE-S3), but instead only nginx-S3. And direct blob url is not visible to end client